# stop executing the loop until the function is completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, asynchronous, animation

I'm trying to build a simple game in React and I need to make an animation where a set of blocks change their color to orange for 1 sec and go back to white. This operation needs to happen one by one.

Here is my game with an array of divs:

[image: this is my game with an array of divs]

And let's say the array is [1,3,5,6]
I want to loop through that array and add a class with bg color to each div for a second and then removed it

I tried many things but the close I can get I that all the divs change their color at the same, not one by one

this is my code with a function that is starting by pressing "next lvl" and another async function

```js
const displayBlocks = async (key) => {  
    let promise = new Promise((res,rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
                divArray.classList.remove('active');
                res('color removed');
            }, 500)
        });
        console.log(key);
        ref.current.childNodes[key].classList.add('active'); 
        let result = await promise;     
        return result;          
}

const handleNewGame = () => {
    blockArray = []
    // generate array with random cells according to points
    for (let i = 0;i< props.points;i++) {
        let key = Math.floor(Math.random() * (props.board.length)) + 0;
        displayBlocks(key).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            blockArray.push(key);
        })                   
    }
    console.log(blockArray);
}
```

I tried many solutions with async or without but none of them worked. Can you tell me how can I stop the execution of the loop until the displayBlock functions are completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Can't test it at the moment, might run into the same problem

Your `displayBlocks` method is not awaitable. Have you tried something like

```
const displayBlocks = async (key) => {  
                return new Promise((res,rej) => { // return with promise to make it awaitable
                    setTimeout(() => {
                            divArray.classList.remove('active');
                            res('color removed');
                        }, 500)
                    });
                    console.log(key);
                    ref.current.childNodes[key].classList.add('active'); 
                    let result = await promise;     
                    return result;          

    }


    const handleNewGame = () => {
        blockArray = []
        // generate array with random cells according to points
        for (let i = 0;i< props.points;i++) {
            let key = Math.floor(Math.random() * (props.board.length)) + 0;
            var res = await displayBlocks(key); // await should halt the loop
            console.log(res);
            blockArray.push(key);                               
        }
        console.log(blockArray);
    }
```

Comment: I had to put all code into that returned Promise but it worked! 
thank you very much for help :D

Answer (score 0):

If you share the full working code in some online code editor I can fix it, but for now, I will share some pseudo code that you can convert into real code.

The idea is, if you want your divs change color 1 by 1, then add the class also one by one, keep track of the time in your calculation. See the pseudo code below,

```
function displayBlock (index) {
    let duration = 1000
    let waitTime = index * duration
    let thisDiv = divArray[index]

    // Now wait for waitTime amount of time before adding the OrangeClass
    setTimeout(() => {
        thisDiv.addClass('OrangeClass')

         //Now from this point, wait for another 1 sec and remove the OrangeClass
         setTimeout(() => {
             thisDiv.removeCLass('OrangeClass')
         }, duration)

    }, waitTime)

}
```

If you can perfectly implement it, it should work as per your expectation. Just do some trial and error.

You can do it. Cheers :)

Comment: Wow, thats worked. I try this solution before but i had to mess something up because it wasnt worked as aexpected. 
But the problem with this solution is the delay beetwen lightinh up next block is different every time, propably because of the waitTime variable but i know it must be there for te set timeout to work
IS there any workaround?

Comment: I have changed the fixed 1000 ms to a variable named "duration". I don't understand why you are getting "delay different every time", because with this code the index 0 block will be lightened up instantly then after 1 sec it will turn off and index 1 div will light up, and so on and so forth. So after every 1 sec previous div will turn OFF and next div should turn ON

Comment: sorry it was my first post here, thanks for your help :)

Comment: If it was really helpful, can you please mark it as selected, or at least upvote my answer? That would help the effort a lot. Thanks and welcome to StackOverflow :)